# Restore MySQL database dump on Windows machine using command line

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on my machine, and I have an empty database my_database.  I'd like to restore a database dump, originally from my shared server, into this empty database.  The database dump is stored at C:/My Document Names Have Spaces/my_dump.sql

I've tried:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p my_database < "C:/My Document Names Have Spaces/my_dump.sql";
```

... and many variants thereon (different quotes, different slashes), and I keep getting syntax errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post an example of the syntax errors you're getting.

Comment: Error message reads: Error 1604 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Comment: I am running this from a mysql> command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the database you are loading the mysqldump into iwth the -D option (nospace between -D and database bame)

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p -Dmy_database < 
"C:/My Document Names Have Spaces/my_dump.sql";
```

Or may you want to do this interactively.

Do the following:

1) Goto that directory in a DOS Window

```
C:> cd "C:\My Document Names Have Spaces"
```

2) Login to mysql client

```
C:\My Document Names Have Spaces> mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

3) set yourself to the my_database

```
mysql> use my_database
```

3) load that file

```
mysql> source my_dump.sql
```

Watch the fireworks from there !!!

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I was unable to go to the directory in a DOS window (stayed stubbornly stuck on H: drive) and DOS window also would not load msql ('mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command')  Going to mysql and saying use my_database then source my_dump has potential, the error message changes to Error 22 Failed to Open File

Answer (score 1):

It worked:

```
mysql> use my_database
mysql> source C:\My Document Names Have Spaces\\My Second Directory Names Do Too\\my_dump.sql
```